# Move to the first/last non-whitespace character of the column ("vertical W/B/E")

Tags: cursor-movement, cursor-motions

For instance move from (the cursor is on the letter in bold italic, in the second column)

```
blablabla
blablabla
blablabla
blablabla
  bla
  bla
  bla
bLablabla
l@st
```

to

```
blablabla
blablabla
blablabla
blablabla
  bla
  bla
  bla
bLablabla
l@st
```

and then to the "@". That would be "vertical `E`". And the same for `W` (move from the initial position to the capital "L") and `B` (@ → L → first l).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting. Vertical analogues of word motion commands. I'm not aware of any native way to do this so my first thought is to just start with regex searches. Turns out doing such searches in one step is not trivial but still viable.

First a couple notes:

- To make it quite a bit easier I'm using (vertical) `WORD` motions (`W`,`B`,`E`) rather than `word` (`w`,`b`,`e`). The latter is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` OR a sequence of other non-blank characters while a `WORD` is just `\S+`. In fact, your example is actually demonstrating `WORD` motion because otherwise the second `e` would end up on the `L` not the `@`. *[Note: the question originally referred to `w`,`b`,`e` but has since been edited.]*
- The patterns will use 'very magic' flag to reduce length and improve readability.
- To start, my pattern will be based on a fixed column number (4). This will be made variable later.

Starting with `E`...

```
\v%4v\S.*(\n.{3}\s|\n.{,3}\n|%$)
```

- `\v` - very magic
- `%4v\S` - in column 4 there must be a non-whitespace character (our `WORD` char)
- `.*` - slurp up anything remaining on the line
- `(..|..|..)` - parens indicating any of the following three patterns are allowed on the next line...
- `\n.{3}\s` - after the current line's newline the next line starts with three characters followed by whitespace (in the cursor column)
- `\n.{,3}\n` - after the newline there are three or fewer characters total on the next line
- `%$` - there is no next line as indicated by this *end of file* token (allowing vertical `E` motion to end on the last line of the buffer)

This doesn't do us much good as a standalone pattern. The best thing to do is put it in a function. The key lines will look like:

```
let curcol = getcurpos()[2]
let prevcol = curcol - 1
call searchpos('\v%' . curcol . 'v\S.*\n(.{' . prevcol . '}\s|.{,' . prevcol . '}\n)')
```

This just looks at whatever column the cursor is currently on and inserts that and one less into the previously discussed pattern.

Combining the above pattern and similar patterns for the other motions and parameterizing by motion types `W`, `B` and `E` I have this:

```
func! VertWordMotion(motion)
    let curcol = getcurpos()[2]
    let prevcol = curcol - 1
    if a:motion == 'E'
        call searchpos('\v%' . curcol . 'v\S.*(\n.{' . prevcol . '}\s|\n.{,' . prevcol . '}\n|%$)', 'W')
    elseif a:motion == 'B'
        call searchpos('\v(%' . curcol . 'v\s.*\n|^.{,' . prevcol . '}\n|%^).{' . prevcol . '}\zs\S', 'bW')
    elseif a:motion == 'W'
        call searchpos('\v(%' . curcol . 'v\s.*|^.{,' . prevcol . '})\n.{' . prevcol . '}\zs\S', 'W')
    else
        echohl ErrorMsg | echo 'Not a valid motion: ' . a:motion | echohl None
    endif
endfunc
```

Finally, create mappings like these:

```
nnoremap <leader>E :call VertWordMotion('E')<CR>
nnoremap <leader>B :call VertWordMotion('B')<CR>
nnoremap <leader>W :call VertWordMotion('W')<CR>
```

Comment: My answer is `call searchpos('\v(%' . curcol . 'v\s.*|^.{,' . prevcol . '})\n.{' . prevcol . '}\zs\S', 'W')`

Comment: One thing I'd like it to do is ignore single spaces surrounded by non-whitespace characters. As it is now it slips in between spaces and, for example, it would skip from the closing bracket in `getcurpos()[2]` to the dot in `%' . curcol`, under `elseif a:move == 'B'`, instead of stopping by in the line below `if a:move == 'E'`.

Comment: I'd like to keep it limited to single spaces, so it disregards comments further away.

Comment: If I'm understanding you, your wanting behavior that doesn't align with the Vim commands. Two thoughts on that. First, you'll be changing your original question which is frowned upon once a valid answer has been posted. Second, I think your original question is interesting and generally useful (I upvoted it). If instead it had quirky custom behavior that doesn't match anything familiar to other users then I think the value of the question is diminished. Might be able to help as an addendum but would rather not change what's already there (except to fix a bug, for example).

Comment: I agree actually, still I'd like to know how it could be done because I've tried somewhat heuristically and now I'm curious about the proper way.

Comment: Sure it is :-)
Back to peaceful topics... I think that adding `W` to each `searchpos` to avoid wrapping around at the end of file results in a better behaviour, except that now `VertWordMove('E')` doesn't jump to the last block of text and `VertWordMove('B')` to the first. Do you have any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: I'd make the mappings `<silent>`, also I've tried to make them available in visual mode by simply remapping with `noremap` but then the function gets out of visual mode when i use it. I don't really need it to avoid slipping in between spaces, but if you could help me solve these two last issues I think it would make a solid tool for moving around quickly. Thanks :-)

Comment: I fixed the start/end of file issues. Will try to look at the visual mode thing but no promises on that one.

Answer (score 2):

Although I think @BLayer's answer is very good, I also think it is worth mentioning the [vim-columnmove](https://github.com/machakann/vim-columnmove) plugin:

> This plugin implements several keymappings to move cursor in vertical direction.

The plugin implements columnwise versions of the following motions:

- `f`, `t`
- `F`, `T`
- `;`, `,`
- `w`, `b`
- `W`, `B`
- `e`, `ge`
- `E`, `gE`

I've used it for some time and finds it works very well.

Comment: What version of vim do you use? It's the first plugin I try to install, I'm on Vim 8 and I've used the built-in package loading functionality, but it doesn't work. I've followed [this tutorial](https://shapeshed.com/vim-packages/), I don't know if it's me or if maybe there are compatibility issues between Vim 8 and the plugin (it's been last updated in 2016).

Comment: It works for me both on Vim 8 and on neovim. Note, though, that the `<meta>...` bindings do not work properly in terminal Vim. But I think they work with gvim, and they do work well in neovim. My settings for the plugin are [here](https://github.com/lervag/dotvim/blob/30e4e27/vimrc#L648), in case that might be helpful.